# Line of code is not registering after if statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created enemy respawn function after specific amount of time, but the if statement `Death = false;` does not register, therefore not stopping `Timer += Time.deltaTime`, and rapidly spawning unlimited amout of enemy's.

How would I go about fixing this code?

```
void Start()
{        
    Death = false;
    this.gameObject.name = EnemyName + "spawn point";
}


void Update()
{
    if (Death == true)
    {
        Timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (Timer >= Cooldown)
    {            
        Instantiate(Enemy);

        Enemy.transform.position = transform.position;
        LastEnemy = GameObject.Find(Enemy.name + "(Clone)");
        LastEnemy.name = EnemyName;

        Death = false;

        Timer = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing shown here would result in the behavior you describe. However, `LastEnemy = GameObject.Find(Enemy.name + "(Clone)");` is not going to do what you want it to. You should do `LastEnemy = Instantiate(Enemy);`.

Comment: where is the code that sets Death equal to  true?

Answer (score 0):

If there is something wrong with the `if` statement, then there is something wrong with the condition. so check the part of code that sets `Death` equal to `true`.

The right code for instantiating an enemy :

```
GameObject LastEnemy = Instantiate(Enemy, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
LastEnemy.name = EnemyName;
```